# Spring security prevent user from manipulating url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

A supervisor user that is logged in can view his subordinates in an html table.
Each item has a link and supervisor can view the selected subordinate in detail like personal information etc...
When supervisor clicks the link it will be redirected to `/view/123` where 123 is the id of the selected subordinate. A controller will handle the GET request `'/view/{id}'`.

The problem here is that supervisor can guess any numbers after `/view/`. Possible solutions would be

1. Change it to POST which is more secure however client can still create a dummy post request which still not safe.
2. Add token in the url`'/view/123?token=54gX23r'`for additional validation, for example supervisor changed it to `'/view/456?token=54gX23r'` id and token is not match and the request will be rejected by server.

I think solution no. 2 will resolve the issue however I'm not sure whether spring has a built in mechanism which is similar to it like CSRF token.

Comment: Use `@PreAuthorize` and check if the logged in user is allowed to access the given usr.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank i'll check it, but do you have related articles that exactly match my problem?

Comment: The spring security reference guide explains this. http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize. However that uses spring security ACL. You could do a simple check if the requested user has the current user as a manager. something like `#user.manager == authentication.name` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security has build-in CSRF token solution. To apply it, you need to attach a `<csrf/>` tag inside the `<http>` Spring Security tag where you can set secured urls and other stuff and then in your jsp or whatever form include those tags.

> If you are using Spring MVC `<form:form>` tag or Thymeleaf 2.1+ and are
>   using `@EnableWebSecurity`, the `CsrfToken` is automatically included for
>   you

More details: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Oh, `<csrf/>` tag is applied by default, too when using Spring Security

Comment: I'm not looking for CSRF token solution.

Answer (score 1):

Singning the id would be a solution (by adding a token / signature), but I would rather suggest to do a check whether the user is allowed to view this subordinate

The token could just be created like:

```
DigestUtils.md5DigestAsHex(("123" + "MY_SECRET").getBytes())
```

When accessing the resource you can just recreate the token and verify it is the same as sent by the request